# Trying to save JSON string into a class to parce between activities (NPE)

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, gson

I am trying to save my JSON string into a class so that I can pass around that object between activities and not lose any data when pressing the back button. However as I try to set the string into the object I receive a `NullPointerException`. Here is the code for my java file where the exception is occurring, the class java file, and the error. I am using GSON to serialize and deserialize. Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

NewLocation.java

```
package com.customledsupply.ledaudit;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


import com.google.gson.Gson;




public class NewLocation extends ActionBarActivity {

    public EditText editCoName;
    public EditText editCoAddress;
    public EditText editCoContact;
    public EditText editSqFt;
    public EditText editTaxed;
    public EditText editConcerns;
    public JSON_String json;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_location);
        findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SaveInfo();
                Intent i = new Intent(NewLocation.this, RoomList.class);
                i.putExtra("json", (Parcelable) json);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        editCoName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CoName);
        editCoAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CoAddress);
        editCoContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CoContact);
        editSqFt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SqFt);
        editTaxed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Taxed);
        editConcerns = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Concerns);

        SaveInfo();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LoadInfo();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        SaveInfo();
    }

    public void SaveInfo() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        CompanyInfo companyInfo = new CompanyInfo();

        companyInfo.setName(editCoName.getText().toString());
        companyInfo.setAddress(editCoAddress.getText().toString());
        companyInfo.setContact(editCoContact.getText().toString());
        companyInfo.setTaxed(editTaxed.getText().toString());
        companyInfo.setSqFt(editSqFt.getText().toString());
        companyInfo.setConcerns(editConcerns.getText().toString());

        json.setJson(gson.toJson(companyInfo));

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("json", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("json", json.getJson());
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void LoadInfo() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("json", MODE_PRIVATE);
        json.setJson(sharedPreferences.getString("json", null));

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        CompanyInfo companyInfo = gson.fromJson(json.getJson(), CompanyInfo.class);
        if (companyInfo != null) {
            editCoName.setText(companyInfo.getName());
            editCoAddress.setText(companyInfo.getAddress());
            editCoContact.setText(companyInfo.getContact());
            editTaxed.setText(companyInfo.getTaxed());
            editSqFt.setText(companyInfo.getSqFt());
            editConcerns.setText(companyInfo.getConcerns());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_location, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.home:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPage.class));
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

JSON_String.java

```
package com.customledsupply.ledaudit;

public class JSON_String {

        private String json;

        public void setJson(String json) {
            this.json = json;
        }

        public String getJson() {
            return json;
        }


    }
```

NPE error

```
08-03 08:46:52.081  24423-24423/com.customledsupply.ledaudit E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.customledsupply.ledaudit, PID: 24423
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.customledsupply.ledaudit/com.customledsupply.ledaudit.NewLocation}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.customledsupply.ledaudit.NewLocation.SaveInfo(NewLocation.java:78)
            at com.customledsupply.ledaudit.NewLocation.onCreate(NewLocation.java:52)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you tell which line showing the nullPointer?

Comment: The expression `sharedPreferences.getString("json", null)` may be `null` which will certainly throw a NPE.

Comment: The error shows the `NullPointerException` happening at the line `json.setJson(gson.toJson(companyInfo));` in `SaveInfo()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `json` is `null`, hence the error. To `onCreate` add

`json = new JSON_String();`

If you want to keep passing the object between activites, and not lose it when back button is pressed, you should use `startActivityForResults()`. This will require you to implement a couple of methods that take care of passing objects between activities. [This is a good tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

Comment: @JJStamp No problem. savepopulation is also correct with his comment regarding Parcelable, it is unnecessary with your simple object.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to cast your json to Parcelable:

```
i.putExtra("json", (Parcelable) json);
```

Just pass as a string and in your RoomList.class get from bundle. Cast it to your class with gson and use it.

Comment: Wouldn't this still get deleted by pressing back or should i pass another bundle when the back button is pressed?

Comment: You're saving your data in onDestroy(). if you save in onPause() in your all activities which you use same object and load in onResume() you can get changes of your object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is You didn't initialize your  `JSON_String` class. You need to initialize the  `JSON_String` like

`public JSON_String json =  new JSON_String();`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to initlize the json string?

Comment: Where would I initialize it? If i were to initialize the string in `OnCreate` wouldn't that overwrite my JSON string every time the activity is destroyed and recreated, like when the back button is pressed?